# Android Google Inbox like Floating Action Button Overlay

Tags: android, overlay, floating-action-button

How we can show an overlay when floating action button menu expands.
[image]

Comment: What library are you using for your floating action menu (FAM)? The overlay itself would just be some `View` with the desired white-with-alpha translucency, initially set to `View.GONE`. The only tricky part is getting control when the FAM opens, and for that, we would need to know what FAM library you are using.

Comment: I am using com. getbase.flaotingactionbutton library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) library.

It's got really cool features.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.